# Does anyone have any experience with completely recoding the layout of the Wordpress admin section?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, admin

I'm just doing some research into how the Wordpress admin panel might be completely redesigned into a different layout altogether, and wondered if anyone here has experimented with this before?

I'm aware that you can inject a custom stylesheet which can be used to override current styles and move certain things around,  but I wondered how it might be possible to use different HTML markup as well?

Any insight or links to articles about it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [A minimalistic admin theme for a WP 3 install](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/16039)

Comment: @Pekka웃, do you know this one: http://devpress.com/plugins/dp-dashboard/ ?

Comment: @brasofilo nope, but it looks interesting!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't easily change the HTML of wp-admin. Unlike the front which separates logic from visualization, wp-admin scripts contain both HTML and executed code, as you can see in [wp-admin/users.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/users.php).

You can get pretty far changing the CSS and other reused items like the menu and header/footer. A good number of things you can change is describe in the article [How To Customize The WordPress Admin Easily](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/17/customize-wordpress-admin-easily/).

Comment: But you can change the html in the .php files and update the css accordingly. Yes it's not as simple as working with a static html page but if you're comfortable with PHP it is achievable.

Comment: I wouldn't advise that. Those files will be overwritten when updating WordPress. And an outdated WP can be dangerous.

Comment: True but if you're prepared to maintain it, it's still possible. I've edited my answer to say it's essentially not worth it anyway.

Comment: @ssbrewster, [this is what happens when you hack the core](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/b/b3/donthack.jpg) and also you may break some things other plugins rely on to make their work...

Comment: @brasofilo ha ha excellent (just so you know I have never hacked the core!)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone. I realise it's not a simple task, and never expected an easy solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Within the Wordpress files you have all of the code so you can do with it as you wish. Take a look at the files in the wp-admin folder when you download Wordpress. And try [searching on Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=develop%20wordpress%20admin%20ui&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-GB%3a%7Breferrer%3asource%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=&rlz=1I7SUNC_en&redir_esc=&ei=5agaUYOvJsjQ0QWK-oDQCQ#hl=en&tbo=d&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-GB%3a%7Breferrer%3asource%7D&rlz=1I7SUNC_en&sclient=psy-ab&q=redesign%20wordpress%20admin%20ui&oq=redesign%20wordpress%20admin%20ui&gs_l=serp.3...4361.5378.0.5621.8.8.0.0.0.4.232.1125.1j6j1.8.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.2.serp.iPGghYo3eo8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42261806,d.d2k&fp=686385675783a4fd&biw=1366&bih=600). Or go the [plugin route](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wordpress/awesome-wordpress-plugin-your-dashboard/).

But, why redesign the Wordpress admin UI when it's the functionality on the admin side that matters. When you can create custom post types and use great plugins like custom fields, do you really need to redesign the ui?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,

I'm developing a system which uses Wordpress as a core, but everything else is custom. I also don't particularly feel like the admin panel has been designed particularly well...yes ity's better than the average, but not great.